# Slow Internet vs Slow System Response Hosted by Local Server

Tags: client-server, internet

How does slow internet access affects the response time of a web based system hosted on local server that is being access by other clients from the local server?

I'm accessing the web based system on a local server through the ip-address of local server.

ex: 190.168.1.110/local_system/login

Comment: There's no way to know this without actually taking some measurements in your specific environment.

Comment: Can you give me some measurement factors regarding this based your experience? Currently, the web-based system responds well when the internet connection is good but when gets slow when the internet connection is slow too.@RobertHarvey

Comment: The speed of your external Internet connection should have no effect on the operation of a web service that is totally contained on your local network. The exception is if the browser is defective - holding up local traffic while waiting for external traffic. But you would need to be accessing both on the same browser.

Comment: Another possibility is that your internet access is not slowing down at all, but appears to because of a larger than usual amount of Internet traffic on your network (is somebody watching NetFlix? How about porn?). In that case, your local network may be getting saturated.

Comment: By "local" sever, do you mean local area network or localhost?

Comment: Does the server or the browser need to make a internet connection to complete the request? For example, is the server accessing an external API or database, or the page may be loading a CSS/JavaScript file from a CDN?

Comment: Localhost, the browser do not need to connect to the internet to complete the request. All necessary files/libraries are provided locally.@LieRyan

Answer (score 1):

A purely local server should not slow down when its internet connection slows down. Indeed, it should be able to run without an internet connection at all. But there are a variety of common scenarios when a local server does make internet requests, and you may want to locate such occurrences and remove them. Some common ones include:

- calling out to xml schema locations in order to validate xml files
- attempting to perform reverse dns requests on local ip addressees with an incorrectly configured dns resolver that forwards such requests to the internet
- producing web pages that refer to scripts, images, fonts, or style sheets that are hosted online

Comment: None of the occurrences you have mentioned affects the slowness of the response, i guess there are other factors then and it doesn't include the internet connection.@Jules